# Threejs Geometry and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, three.js, geometry

I would like to write correct types for the Mesh Vertices and Faces.

In the first example, I create a new Mesh, and when I want to access Vertices and Faces from geometry, I get a few errors:

```
const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
const geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
const newMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(newMesh);

const { vertices, faces } = newMesh.geometry;
// Error: Property 'vertices' does not exist on type 'BufferGeometry | Geometry'
// Error: Property 'faces' does not exist on type 'Geometry | BufferGeometry'.

newMesh.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
// Error: Property 'colorsNeedUpdate' does not exist on type 'Geometry | BufferGeometry'.
```

In the second example, I get Mesh from the Scene, and then I get the following error:

```
const mesh = scene.getObjectByName('boxMesh');
const geometry = mesh.geometry; 
// Property 'geometry' does not exist on type 'Object3D'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By accessing the geometry via the mesh (`newMesh.geometry`) you get the geometry typed like the `geometry` property on the Mesh class. Apparently the property supports two different types of geometry so you get a union: `Geometry | BufferGeometry`.

If you know exactly what type of geometry is used you can just assert the type of the property value:

```
const { vertices, faces } = <THREE.Geometry>newMesh.geometry;
```

If you do not know the type of `geometry` you need some conditional logic, e.g. using something like:

```
const geometry = newMesh.geometry;
if (geometry instanceof THREE.Geometry)
    // geometry will be typed as Geometry here
else
    // geometry will be typed as BufferGeometry here
```

---

In the second case you use `getObjectByName` which always returns objects of the most basic type `Object3D`. Here you also have to assert the type of the result accordingly.

```
// Assuming the thing named boxMesh is a Mesh...
// The <any> assertion prevents additional type errors.
const mesh = <THREE.Mesh><any>scene.getObjectByName('boxMesh');
```

Comment: When I write like this: 

const mesh = <THREE.Mesh>scene.getObjectByName('boxMesh');
I het error: "Type 'Object3D | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Mesh | undefined'.
  Type 'Object3D' is missing the following properties from type 'Mesh': geometry, material,"

Comment: For errors like this you can first assert it as `any`: `<THREE.Mesh><any>scene.getObjectByName('boxMesh');`

Comment: There should be a better solution than to use any

Comment: Well, there isn't. The function `getObjectByName` should not return `Object3D` in the first place but have a generic parameter deriving from `Object3D`, so you could specify the return type in the function call. Casting to `any` first is the standard way of solving this issue (see [double assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html#double-assertion) section in documentation).

Comment: @john_per Actually, the single type assertion should work in this case because `Mesh` is a subtype of `Object3D`. I tried it myself and do not get any errors, Are you using the wrong `Mesh` class?

Comment: Solve it in this way: 

const mesh: any = scene.getObjectByName('boxMesh');

const geometry: THREE.Geometry = mesh.geometry;