# Three JS. "Property 'material' does not exist on type 'Object3D'" error when getObjectByName is used

Tags: typescript, three.js

I am getting material elements of my visualization by `this.scene.getObjectByName("MeshName").material` the elements exist everything is working and when I print it it works. I need it for changing opacity. But the problem is that I am getting "Property 'material' does not exist on type 'Object3D'" error and due to this I can't run ng build and I need to use `// @ts-ignore` to ignore it. Does someone know why it is like this?

Comment: I believe this has been [addressed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58606019/threejs-geometry-and-typescript) You basically have to tell TS that you're expecting a Mesh: `const myThing = (<THREE.Mesh>scene.getObjectByName('MeshName'));` This Then you can access its material: `myThing.material`;

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that the return type of `getObjectByName()` is `Object3D`. And objects of this type do not have a `material` property.

So if you are sure that "MeshName" is the name of a mesh, you have to cast the returned object to a material and then access `material`:

```
(this.scene.getObjectByName("MeshName") as THREE.Mesh).material
```

Comment: But it seems that in "Mesh" there is no opacity property and it is also throwing an error: Property 'opacity' does not exist on type 'Material | Material[]'. Property 'opacity' does not exist on type 'Material[]'

Comment: It's necessary to cast to a single material since the `material` property can also hold an array of materials.

Comment: Sorry for long break. To be sure I don't understand how to do this casting. Can tou tell me more?